# AWS S3 policy - cross account access to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on the project where I need to share S3 bucket with 2 other teams using **2 different AWS accounts (User B and User C)**. These two teams need rights to upload and download the datasets to s3 bucket, and later on I should be able to download the content which they upload.

I use following bucket policy

```
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                    "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3::: bucketname-test "
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRead",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": [
                     "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:root",
                    "arn:aws:iam::222222222222:root"
               
                ]
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListMultipartUploadParts"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname-test/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks to this **User B** and **User C** are able to upload and download the content to the shared s3 bucket.

However, me as **User A** and at the same time **admin of the account where the S3 bucket is created** I am not able to download content which is uploaded by **User B** and **User C**.

How can I solve the issue?

Comment: When you upload with user B and user C, try uploading with ACL set to `bucket-owner-full-control`. From my experience, if the bucket owner doesn't control the object, the bucket policy doesn't really apply to those objects

Comment: Thanks @jordanm- I will test it!

Comment: The policy you've shown doesn't allow any uploading at all. Presumably you have that and aren't showing it to us. See how to modify the bucket policy to require that uploaders assign bucket-owner-full-control [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-require-object-ownership/). You don't just *want* uploaders to assign this, you want to *force* them to assign it. Otherwise you can't do anything with the objects they've uploaded (except delete them).

Comment: Thanks jordanm it worked! I will follow @jarmod tip to set it up as part of bucket policy.